# Grab mysql results for a different variable if it doesn't exist for specific variable

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm currently experimenting with the ability to support multiple languages on my website.

I have a query which selects rows from a database based on a few variables.

```
$db->run("SELECT id, language, text FROM language WHERE language=? AND module=? AND method=?", [$language, $module, $method])->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_GROUP|\PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE);
```

The return that I get is similar to this:

```
Array
(
    [title] => Array
        (
            [language] => english
            [text] => Log In
        )

    [button] => Array
        (
            [language] => english
            [text] => Log In
        )
)
```

My question comes in when the user has selected a non-English language, as english is the default language for my site. I want this query to fall-back to the English translations if a specific translation is not available for the selected language.

For example, let's say I have a `spanish` translation ONLY for the `title` key above. The query would currently only return this

```
Array
(
    [title] => Array
        (
            [language] => spanish
            [text] => Iniciar sesión
        )
)
```

However, I would like to fall-back to the English translations if a Spanish one doesn't exist. So my expected result looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [title] => Array
        (
            [language] => spanish
            [text] => Iniciar sesión
        )

    [button] => Array
        (
            [language] => english
            [text] => Log In
        )
)
```

How can I make my query fall back like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COALESCE(t2.id, t1.id) id,
       COALESCE(t2.language, t1.language) language,
       COALESCE(t2.text, t1.text) text
FROM language t1
LEFT JOIN language t2 ON t1.module = t2.module
                     AND t1.method = t2.method
                     AND t2.language = ?
WHERE t1.language = 'english'
  AND t1.module = ? 
  AND t1.method = ?
```

Comment: source code only answers are discouraged here, as you know